# How do I send JSON data to node.js server using fetch?

Tags: node.js, json, angular, http, fetch

I have a node.js back-end server.  Front-end is running on Angular 10.
I want to pass data from front-end to back-end using fetch

Front-end code :

```
testmariadb($event: MouseEvent) {
    return fetch('/api/customQuery', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        sqlQuery: 'SELECT * FROM software'
      })
    })
  }
```

Back-end code

```
app.post('/api/customQuery', async (req, res) => {
  let test = req.body['sqlQuery'] 
  console.log(test)
})
```

I get this error :

```
  let test = req.body['sqlQuery'] 
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sqlQuery')
    at /home/erwan/Documents/GitHub/serverAltertManager/index.js:90:22
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: have you tested your POST API (using postman, cUrl, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Are using the middleware properly

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
```

Comment: The last line was missing in my code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
testmariadb() {
   fetch('APIURL', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        key: 'Value'
      })
    }).then((result)=>{
        return result
     })
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: I found it didn't work (no data in req.body in Express) without the headers.